# Maker Based AR.Js and A-Frame - Visual Problem, Clipping Mesh

Tags: html, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js, glitch-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgiOs.jpg)

The White Mesh bellow Clips through the roof and the further you move the object, the worse it gets.

Piotr Adam Milewski answered this question, from another person and gave this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63143382/18310645
But i don't understand a thing about coding so i don't know how to implement it in my code, can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <a-marker preset="hiro">
        <a-entity
          position="0 0 0"
          scale="0.2 0.2 0.2"
          gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.global/0653babd-a1b3-490a-9927-4d95dd7c9ffa/Capela%20das%20Penhas.glb?v=1645748288220"
        ></a-entity>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll try to make a more comprehensive answer by the weekend ;)

Answer (score 0):

If Your model looks properly in the [gltf-viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/), but with ar.js You're experiencing clipping like this:
[image]

it is very likely, that you need to use a `logarithmicDepthBuffer` in your renderer.

Luckily, it's very easy - just add the `renderer` component to the `<a-scene>` element with the desired property:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true">
```

Which should result in a more desired image:

[image]

Check out both proper and clipping models [here](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/ar)

---

Why is it happening? The model looks small, but actually it's huge just rescaled (100times, from what sketchfab exporter gave me). Also the marker makes it even more rescaled (marker determines the unit size. The `<marker>` content is rescaled from 1m to whatever the print size).

If we'd lose the scaling, the model would be so huge, the clipping parts would be so far away, that determining their precise distance from the camera would be wasteful. So you need to switch to a logarithmic depth buffer, which is designed to have better precision for greater distances.

Model by [Boooooop](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/low-poly-medieval-island-361f02265937462a8969d78c5be1fc6c)